# Importing .csv gives \x0P\x0a\x0g\x0e\x0 for values

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to import a .csv file generated by Google Adsense's Export to CSV button, but I am running into what I presume to be encoding issues.

The contents of the downloaded .csv file are:

```
Date    Page views  Clicks  Page CTR    CPC (USD)   Page RPM (USD)  Estimated earnings (USD)
2014-02-20  381480  2673    0.70%   0.23    1.61    615.40
2014-02-21  304515  2206    0.72%   0.21    1.52    463.32
2014-02-22  192661  1491    0.77%   0.21    1.59    307.19
2014-02-23  230952  1706    0.74%   0.23    1.70    392.45
2014-02-24  280726  1817    0.65%   0.20    1.31    367.04
2014-02-25  279398  1889    0.68%   0.21    1.40    390.49
2014-02-26  292201  2045    0.70%   0.22    1.55    454.26
```

When outputted to the browser or viewed in a text editor such as Notepad++, the characters are shown as expected (like above). However, when I step through it in my IDE, I am getting the following as my array for the first row:

```
array = 
  0: string = "\x02\x00\x01\x04\x0-\x00\x02\x0-\x02\x00\x0"
  1: string = "\x03\x08\x01\x04\x08\x00\x0"
  2: string = "\x02\x06\x07\x03\x0"
  3: string = "\x00\x0.\x07\x00\x0%\x0"
  4: string = "\x00\x0.\x02\x03\x0"
  5: string = "\x01\x0.\x06\x01\x0"
  6: string = "\x06\x01\x05\x0.\x04\x00\x0"
```

I have tried just about every time of encoding conversion I can think of, but nothing seems to make sense of these hex characters.

This is the script I am running to turn it into an array, however, I see the characters as soon as I use file or file_get_contents.

```
$csv = array();
$lines = file($path, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

foreach ($lines as $key => $value)
{              
    $row = str_getcsv($value, "\t");

    $csv[$key]['Date'] = $row[0];
    $csv[$key]['Site'] = $row[1];
    $csv[$key]['Pageviews'] = $row[2];
    $csv[$key]['Clicks'] = $row[3];
    $csv[$key]['PageCTR'] = str_replace('%', '', $row[4]);
    $csv[$key]['CPC'] = $row[5];
    $csv[$key]['PageRPM'] = $row[6];
    $csv[$key]['Earnings'] = $row[7];    
}      

echo '<pre>';
print_r($csv);
echo '</pre>';
```

How can I turn `\x02\x06\x07\x03\x0` into 2673?

Comment: What IDE are you using? I suspect it may be at fault here, not your script — some of the values it's reporting (e.g. `"\x0-"` amd `"\x0."`) are nonsensical.

Comment: I'm using PhpED. I thought it was the IDE at first also, but I can't do any math on the variables, which makes me think it isn't just that.